# Levene's Test on SPSS doesn't show $p$-value

Tags: anova, spss, experiment-design, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

I have a factorial design with three factors. The model looks like this
$$y_{ijk} = \mu + \alpha_i + \beta_j + \gamma_k + (\alpha \beta)_{ij} + (\beta \gamma)_{jk} + \epsilon_{ijk}$$
where $i \in \{ 1, 2, 3\}, j \in \{1, 2\}$ and $k \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$. 
The three order interaction has been dismissed since this is a design with no replication. Also, the second order interaction $(\alpha \gamma)_{ik}$ has been eliminated after getting a $p$-value of roughly $0.3$ in a previous ANOVA table where that interaction was considered. However, when running the homocedasticity test (which I believe is suppposed to be Levene's test), I get a table that looks like this

\begin{align*}
F \qquad& df1 \qquad df2 \qquad Sig.\\
 \qquad & 29 \qquad \quad 0
\end{align*}
that is, no statistic and no $p$-value whatsoever.

> What does this mean? Can I check the homocedasticity assumption with other test rather than Levene's (and residual plots) for a design experiment like this one?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure why this is being voted for closure as off-topic as it seems to me to have a statistical content. The problem would still arise if the OP did it by hand although that would have highlighted the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have 30 cells each with one observation. The test of homoscedasticity checks whether those 30 variances are equal. The variance of a single observation is zero so you are not going to find any test which gives you a sensible answer. You need to rethink why you want to carry out such a test.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks you! I really didn't think wht Levene's test was actually doing. But isn't homocedasticity an assumption to make when doing a factorial analysis? Does that mean that whenever I have a factorial design with no replications, I can't check if the homocedasticity assumption holds? Or is that assumption meaningless in the first place for that type of design?